# What is the best website solution for playing specific parts of online mp3 files?

Tags: audio, mp3, audio-streaming

Back in **2000** I made an educational website in which we had **hour-long** audio files of lectures on a **RealAudio** server, then I generated hundreds of little **SMIL .ra files** e.g.

**lecture002part053.ra:**

```
...
    <audio src="lecture002.wav" clip-begin="554s" clip-end="612s" />
...
```

then in the HTML I had **links** like this:

```
<a href="http://nnnnn.edu/lecturesparts/lecture002part053.rt">Play part 53</a>
```

And when anyone with the RealAudio **player** would click on the link they would instantly hear only that **small portion** of the .wav file.

The solution worked well, but the RealAudio Server was a bit **expensive** and the RealAudio player was unfortunately a kind of **adware** with ad popups etc.

So ten years later I can imagine there is a better way to do this, **what is the best technology today to stream portions of audio files from a web server, namely, with these features:**

- ability to create hyperlinks that **play small portions** of a large online **.mp3 file**
- a **built-in player** (e.g. Flash or Silverlight), such as [this built-in Flash player one at dotnet rocks](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=517) where -- if you have Flash -- users just see it, click it and it starts playing audio
- is a **free solution** and does not require a separate audio server

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Adobe Flex if you are a programmer.  Then you could create your own and have it behave anyway you want.  Flex is pretty easy for Java or C# programmers to pick up, since the syntax is similar (well minus the MXML part).

I haven't made a MP3 player in Flex 3 but I did make a VideoPlayer with Adobe FlexBuilder.  It was very easy to do and with flash/flex you can have the player look very neat (fading in&out play buttons...).  There is an example on adobe's site on how to build a podcast player in Flex 3, that reads the source URLs from an RSS feed: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Sound_02.html go here and select the sub-node named: *Example PodCast player*.

Hitting your points:

> ability to create hyperlinks that play
>   small portions of a large online .mp3
>   file

You could customize the player to take FlashVars, so that it knows only to play a portion of the file. But if this is for sampling before buying I would suggest just having a short version of the sound file.

> a built-in player (e.g. Flash or
>   Silverlight), such as this built-in
>   Flash player one at dotnet rocks where
>   -- if you have Flash -- users just see it, click it and it starts playing
>   audio

Flex = Flash, so yes

> is a free solution and does not
>   require a separate audio server

No audio server needed but you would need to compile your code.  So you would need FlexBuilder(not Free) or FlashDeveloper(Free).

Comment: I also try using Red5 (open source and free) for those with Java background.

Comment: Does Red5 have a webclient?  Just reading the home page it looks like a good backend streaming server, for serving up the content.